# XCode 9.1 CFNetwork Internal Error URLConnectionLoader spam in swift project

Tags: ios, swift3, cfnetwork, xcode9.1

I'm looking at the console log of my project and see the following sequence of error messages. They are all the same.

**How can I find the source or remove URLConnectionLoader errors from the XCode console log?**

```
    2017-12-12 10:10:00.604139+0700 Project[6386:929833] 6386: CFNetwork internal error 
(0xc01a:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-889.9/Loading/URLConnectionLoader.cpp:315)
```